# How do I resize css loaders?

Tags: css

I'm wondering how I resize css loaders like resize it for mobile users cause I noticed the loaders don't resize for mobile users they just stay the same size no matter the size of the page, I want it to resize itself like text and stuff does. Here's an example of a css loader if you're confused:

http://jsfiddle.net/hdznz09a

```css
#floatBarsG{
 position:relative;
 width:234px;
 height:28px;
 margin:auto;
 margin-top: 13%;
}
.floatBarsG{
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 background-color:rgb(0,0,0);
 width:28px;
 height:28px;
 animation-name:bounce_floatBarsG;
 animation-duration:1.5s;
 animation-direction:normal;
 transform:scale(.3);
}

#floatBarsG_1{
 left:0;
 animation-delay:0.6s;
}
#floatBarsG_2{
 left:29px;
 animation-delay:0.75s;
}
#floatBarsG_3{
 left:58px;
 animation-delay:0.9s;
}
#floatBarsG_4{
 left:88px;
 animation-delay:1.05s;
}
#floatBarsG_5{
 left:117px;
 animation-delay:1.2s;
}
#floatBarsG_6{
 left:146px;
 animation-delay:1.35s;
}
#floatBarsG_7{
 left:175px;
 animation-delay:1.5s;
}
#floatBarsG_8{
 left:205px;
 animation-delay:1.64s;
}
@keyframes bounce_floatBarsG{
 0%{
  transform:scale(1);
  background-color:rgb(0,0,0);
 }

 100%{
  transform:scale(.3);
  background-color:rgb(255,255,255);
 }
}
```

```html
<div id="floatBarsG">
  <div id="floatBarsG_1" class="floatBarsG"></div>
  <div id="floatBarsG_2" class="floatBarsG"></div>
  <div id="floatBarsG_3" class="floatBarsG"></div>
  <div id="floatBarsG_4" class="floatBarsG"></div>
  <div id="floatBarsG_5" class="floatBarsG"></div>
  <div id="floatBarsG_6" class="floatBarsG"></div>
  <div id="floatBarsG_7" class="floatBarsG"></div>
  <div id="floatBarsG_8" class="floatBarsG"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please define what a "css loader" is.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/RokoCB/hdznz09a/2/ use dynamic size like `width:3vh`, or `height:3vh;` (so use `%`, `vw`, `vh` or any other responsive unit) float left your minitinysquares and don't use `left`

Comment: @CharlesMcKelvey they are like this [https://codepen.io/CreativeJuiz/pen/vFBIh](https://codepen.io/CreativeJuiz/pen/vFBIh)

Comment: A loading icon made with css, got it.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Kk I'll try that thanks

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan But the only thing I see wrong with your fiddle is that the bars are smaller :/

Comment: @ThelmaGibson you can always add `min-width:20px; min-height:20px;` if you want. have you tried to resize the fiddle window?

Answer (score 3):

You could use the:

```
transform: scale(0.5);
```

on your:

```
<div id="floatBarsG">
```

element like shown below

```
#floatBarsG{
    position:absolute;
    width: 33%;
    height:28px;
    margin-left: -117px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: 13%;

    transform: scale(0.5);
}
```

in combination with media querys for your desired width's / devices

Articles about media querys:

https://wiki.selfhtml.org/wiki/CSS/Media_Queries
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

JSFIDDLE Example: http://jsfiddle.net/hdznz09a/3/ (Try resizing your browser window)

Comment: you'r welcome (: - I added a jsfiddle for you maybe it'll help!

Answer (score 1):

As said in comments:

- use **dynamic size** like `vh` or `vw`
- `float:left;` your *minitinysquares* and
- don't to `absolute` and `left` values
- don't use `#`ID, **use classes instead** (code reusability)

```css
#floatBarsG{
  position:absolute;
  left:50%; top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.floatBarsG{
  float:left;
  background-color:rgb(0,0,0);
  width:3vh;                        /* Use responsive units */
  height:3vh;
  min-width: 20px;                  /* prevent making them too small */
  min-height: 20px;
  animation:bounce_floatBarsG 1.5s infinite;
  transform:scale(.3);
}
.floatBarsG._1{animation-delay:0.6s;}
.floatBarsG._2{animation-delay:0.75s;}
.floatBarsG._3{animation-delay:0.9s;}
.floatBarsG._4{animation-delay:1.05s;}
.floatBarsG._5{animation-delay:1.2s;}
.floatBarsG._6{animation-delay:1.35s;}
.floatBarsG._7{animation-delay:1.5s;}
.floatBarsG._8{animation-delay:1.64s;}

@keyframes bounce_floatBarsG{
  from{
    transform:scale(1);
    background-color:rgb(0,0,0);
  }
  to{
    transform:scale(.3);
    background-color:rgb(255,255,255);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="floatBarsG">
  <div class="floatBarsG _1"></div>
  <div class="floatBarsG _2"></div>
  <div class="floatBarsG _3"></div>
  <div class="floatBarsG _4"></div>
  <div class="floatBarsG _5"></div>
  <div class="floatBarsG _6"></div>
  <div class="floatBarsG _7"></div>
  <div class="floatBarsG _8"></div>
</div>
```